# MVC4 - best way to have a generic popup message that appears on every page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What's the recommended way in **MVC4** to code a **generic** DIV that slides down from the top and **displays a message**?

Conceptually I'm looking for a **generic messaging system** that can be used **from any page** and that can be executed on the current page or when loading a new page.

Comment: Maybe [noty](http://needim.github.io/noty/)? :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use some of the existing plugins such as [`jGrowl`](https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl) or [`noty`](http://needim.github.io/noty/).

Comment: @Developer, those are client side, javascript plugins. Talking about invoking javascript code from server side hardly makes any sense. A controller is not responsible for the UI. Once the controller has rendered the view to the client you could start executing javascript code to show those notifications. Of course as every controller action you could pass a view model to the corresponding view so that the output of the plugins is customized. Obviously everything will depend on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [Toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr).

This is what we use in our dev. environment. It has lots of functionality which gives advantage over any other.

> ```
> Some important links:
> ```
>
> - See toastr in action at toastr’s [demo page here](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/)
> - Grab toastr from [github](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)

To get some more insight have a look at John Papa's Blog [Simple JavaScript Notifications with toastr](http://www.johnpapa.net/toastr100beta/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a layout template for this and every page that requires the div to show can utilize that layout template. Alternatively you can utilize web helper methods.

For the actual notification (in addition to Dmitrov's post) you can also checkout: [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)